# xUnit's MemberData attribute does not work

Tags: xunit, xunit2

I have a Test Project with xUnit framework

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

  <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
 </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\GameEngine\GameEngine.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm trying to share this test data

```
using System;
namespace GameEngine.Tests
{
 public class InternalHealthDamageTestData
 {       

    public IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[] { 0, 100 };
            yield return new object[] { 1, 99 };
            yield return new object[] { 50, 50 };
            yield return new object[] { 101, 1 };
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In this test Method

```
using Xunit;
namespace GameEngine.Tests
{
 public class NonPlayerCharacterShould
 {
    [Theory]
    //[MemberData("TestData", MemberType =typeof(InternalHealthDamageTestData))]
    [MemberData(nameof(InternalHealthDamageTestData.TestData), MemberType = typeof(InternalHealthDamageTestData))]
    public void TakeDamage(int damage, int expectedHealth)
    {
        NonPlayerCharacter sut = new NonPlayerCharacter();

        sut.TakeDamage(damage);

        Assert.Equal(expectedHealth, sut.Health);
    }
}
}
```

But I get this error:Error de 'GameEngine.GameEngine.Tests.GameEngine.Tests.NonPlayerCharacterShould.TakeDamage'
Salida de la consola:
System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.
Mensaje de resultados:
System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

When I try with [InLineData] all works fine

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to make the property TestData static.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `TestData` property static:

```
using System;
namespace GameEngine.Tests
{
 public class InternalHealthDamageTestData
 {       

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[] { 0, 100 };
            yield return new object[] { 1, 99 };
            yield return new object[] { 50, 50 };
            yield return new object[] { 101, 1 };
        }
    }
  }
}
```